# Check if a directory exists within a google-nativeclient file system?

Tags: c++, file-io, directory, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to check if a directory exists in a Native Client [file system](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/coding/FileIO) but can't find any functions to do it. I tried creating a `PPB_FileRef` for the directory and then opening that using `PPB_FileIO::Open` and then calling `PPB_FileIO::Query` but `PPB_FileIO::Open` returns `PP_ERROR_NOTAFILE` and then the second call fails.

This is the code I have been trying, some of the initialisation is left out for brevity.

```
PP_Instance instance; // initialised elsewhere
PPB_FileRef *fileRefInterface; // initialised elsewhere
PPB_FileIO *fileIOInterface; // initialised elsewhere
PP_Resource fileSystemResource; // initialised elsewhere

PP_Resource fileRefResource = fileRefInterface->Create(
  fileSystemResource,
  "/directory");

PP_Resource fileIOResource = fileIOInterface->Create(instance);

// This call is returning PP_ERROR_NOTAFILE
//
int32_t result = fileIOInterface->Open(
  fileIOResource,
  fileRefResource,
  PP_FILEOPENFLAG_READ,
  PP_BlockUntilComplete()); // this is being called from a background thread.
if (result != PP_OK)
{
  return false;
}

PP_FileInfo info;
result = fileIOInterface->Query(fileIOResource, &info, PP_BlockUntilComplete());
if (result != PP_OK)
{
  return info.type == PP_FILETYPE_DIRECTORY;
}

return false;
```

Is a return value of `PP_ERROR_NOTAFILE` from `PPB_FileIO::Open` for a valid `PPB_FileRef` enough for me to tell it's a directory or is there another better method I should be using?

Thanks, James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently the way to determine if a `PPB_FileRef` refers to a directory is to try to open it and look for a `PP_ERROR_NOTAFILE` return value.

For background `PP_ERROR_NOTAFILE` was added after the branch for `pepper_25` was made, so until `pepper_26` becomes available in the SDK, one should develop with `pepper_canary` to get its definition in `pp_errors.h`. For more details, see the relevant Chrome [change list](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium/src/ppapi.git;a=commitdiff;h=37634b05a36a902276a443a2be6d97f6a2d29154), which specifically mentions that this return value is used when trying to open a directory.

The current behavior is arguably a bit opaque. There is a "dev" (experimental/unfinished) interface `PPB_DirectoryReader` that when released will provide a more direct way to work with directories.